# Suppose that f is a differentiable function, for all $x, xf(x) = x + sin2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing some review problems for my final and I have come across this question:

> Suppose $f$  is  a  differentiable  function such that, for all $x$,  $xf(x) = x + \sin 2x$. Then  $f(0) = \ldots$
>
> $(A) \ 3$
>
> $(B) \ 0$
>
> $(C) \ -5$
>
> $(D) \ 4$
>
> $(E) \ -2$

Currently, I believe that I can omit answer B because that would make this question too "easy". However, I am having a hard time grasping what the $x$ in font of the $f(x)$ has to contribute to the difficulty of this question.

Any hints or help are greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: For $x\neq 0$, $f(x)=1+{\sin 2x\over x}$. Also, the fact that $f$ is differentiable means $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just evaluate at $x=0$, because you get $0=0$ and no information from it. What you can say is that, for $x\ne0$, 
$$
f(x)=1+\frac{\sin 2x}x.
$$
But you are also told that $f$ is continuous, so 
$$
f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}1+\frac{\sin 2x}x=1+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin2x}x=1+2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin2x}{2x}=1+2=3.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the excellent answer! I fully understand it now! :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

For $x\neq0$, divide by $x$, and take the limit as $x\to0$.  This limit is 3. Then it is the value of the function at $0$, since differentiable implies continuous.